# Unrea Engine 4.27.1 project always build everything

Tags: unreal-engine4

I use ue4.27.1, by compiling engine source codes.
However, whenever I try to build sources after changing build configuration 'Develpment editor' to 'DebugGame editor' (or the opposite way) it compiles all 4240 modules.
It compiles more than 2700 modules when I press F5 to play it. It often happens but now this always happens.

"Invalidating makefile" or "create makefile(no makefile)" messages are always shown in the log.

I think this got worse when I created a new class for my project, but I'm not that sure about that.
If anyone got any ideas about this, please, please share your knowledge.

btw it didn't happened with 4.26.2 but happens with 4.27

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this happening on Windows, Mac, or Linux?